# Random forest hyperparmeter tuning using Gradient descent

Tags: r, random-forest, gradient-descent

I would like to use gradient descent for hyper parameter tuning for RF. Does any one has any insights on this, any merits and demerits would be appreciated? Also It would be great if some can share R code.

Comment: The question has already been answered, but what hyperparameters do you want to tune in Random Forests?

Comment: @Firebug: the usual ones like mtry, # of trees, etc.

Comment: From personal experience, `ntree` don't need tuning at all (set as high as you can and be done with it, unless you expect this might actually increase the correlation between trees, given the number of features and samples in your dataset). `mtry` has a lot to do with the randomness of the trees in the ensemble, I usually go with the standard. The parameters that need most fiddling are the ones that deal with weights and stratification, imo.

Comment: @Firebug thanks for the input. i too read that trees and mtry are not worth  fiddling with. mtry is best at root(n). my question was actually in general for a classification where we could use gda for parameter tuning. i think these will be more fit in case of neural net for weights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do gradient descent, you need continuous parameters, and the loss function has to be differentiable with respect to them. Random forests have discrete hyperparameters (e.g. tree depth, number of trees, number of features, etc.). So, unfortunately, gradient descent won't work in this context. Another point is that the loss function (presumably test set error) may have multiple local minima, and any local search procedure can get trapped.

Grid search and random search can be used to explore a broad range of hyperparameter space, and you can hone in on good regions after your initial search. Grid search is popular but, as Simone mentioned, random search can be faster in some cases. This is because some hyperparameters may not strongly affect performance relative to the others. Grid search will waste time exploring different values of the unimportant hyperparameters while holding the more important hyperparameters fixed. Random search updates all hyperparameters on each step, so it has a better chance of hitting the important ones.

> [Bergstra and Bengio (2012)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v13/bergstra12a.html). Random Search for Hyper-Parameter Optimization.

Comment: @yeah make sense, i didnt think this through. That is why Neural net could use GDA for finding weights. tks for your inputs.

Comment: Actually, some of these discrete hyper-parameters are generalizable to non-integer values. E.g. a depth of 8.5 can be taken to mean that for all nodes at depth 8, a coin is flipped to decide whether to add a 9th layer.

Answer (score 3):

I remember I attended an amazing presentation on hyperparameter tuning https://speakerdeck.com/tmls/keras-by-keisuke-kamataki-tmls-number-2

The speaker also pointed out how surprisingly random sampling of hyperparameters works very well.